# how to calculate the mean with conditions?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, mean

Below is the script to generate a reproducible dataframe:

```
id <- c(1:20)
a <- as.numeric(round(runif(20,-40,40),2))
b <- as.numeric(round(a*1.4+60,2))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, a, b))
```

i would like to calculate the mean of "b" under different condition for "a".
for example, what is the mean of "b" when -40 =< a < 0; and what is the mean of "b" when 0=< a <=40.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick `data.table` solution (assuming `coef` is `a`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(MeanASmall = mean(b[-40 <= a & a < 0]),
              MeanABig = mean(b[0 <= a & a <= 40]))]
#    MeanASmall MeanABig
# 1:   33.96727    89.46
```

If `a` range is limited, you could do this quickly with base R too

```
sapply(split(df, df$a >= 0), function(x) mean(x$b))
#     FALSE     TRUE 
#  33.96727 89.46000
```

Comment: May be `%between%` could be also used.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that, the problem is that the conditions aren't equal. LHS is `<=` and RHS is `<`...

Comment: I thought the `incbounds` could be changed, but you are right.

Answer (score 4):

The following solutions would do it:

Subset

```
ndf1<-subset(df, a>=-40 & a<=0)
ndf2<-subset(df, a>=0 & a<=40)

mean(ndf1[,3])
mean(ndf2[,3])
```

Or simpler

```
mean(df[a>=-40 & a<=0, 3]) 
mean(df[a>=0 & a<=40, 3])
```

Using ddply

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(a>=-40 & a<=0), summarize, mean=mean(b))
ddply(df, .(a>=0 & a<=40), summarize, mean=mean(b))
```

Comment: Or using `dplyr` `summarise(df, MeanASmall = mean(b[-40 <=a & a <0]), MeanABig= mean(b[0 <=a & a <=40]))`

Comment: I also don't think there's any use for `which` here

Comment: @David Arenburg: you are right!, I changed it now.